# Generics - Inheriting class modifies a Generic Type and causes a compiler error

Tags: java, generics, gwtp

I have the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class PresenterWithBreadCrumb<V extends View> extends PresenterWidget<V> {
...
```

What I want to do is extend this class and modify the type V.  There is a method that I need in addition to what is provided by the View interface.  The new instance is below.

```
public abstract class ApplicationPanelPresenter<V extends ApplicationPanelPresenter.ApplicationPanelView>
        extends PresenterWithBreadCrumb<ApplicationPanelPresenter.ApplicationPanelView> {

    public interface ApplicationPanelView extends View {
        void clearPanel();
    }
```

When I try to refactor my code, and change the classes that were originally extending `PresenterWithBreadCrumb` to `ApplicationPanelPresenter` I'm introducing a compile error.

Sample before:

```
public class RequirementsPanelPresenter extends PresenterWithBreadCrumb<RequirementsPanelPresenter.MyView>
        implements RequirementsPanelUiHandlers {

    interface MyView extends View, HasUiHandlers<RequirementsPanelUiHandlers> {
    }

    @Inject
    RequirementsPanelPresenter(EventBus eventBus, MyView view) {
        super(eventBus, view);
        getView().setUiHandlers(this);
    }
```

Sample After:

```
public class RequirementsPanelPresenter extends ApplicationPanelPresenter<RequirementsPanelPresenter.MyView>
        implements RequirementsPanelUiHandlers {

    interface MyView extends ApplicationPanelPresenter.ApplicationPanelView, HasUiHandlers<RequirementsPanelUiHandlers> {
    }

    @Inject
    RequirementsPanelPresenter(EventBus eventBus, MyView view) {
        super(eventBus, view);
        getView().setUiHandlers(this);
    }
```

The compile error is on the statement `getView().setUiHandlers(this);`

The compile error is:

> The method setUiHandlers(RequirementsPanelPresenter) is undefined for
>   the type ApplicationPanelPresenter.ApplicationPanelView

**Why is the compiler interpreting "this" as ApplicationPanelPresenter.ApplicationPanelView?  How did my change introduce this error and how can I fix it?**

Additional Context

- The `getView()` method is defined in a parent class and returns a type `V extends View`.
- The setUiHandlers method comes from extended interface HasUiHandlers. The method parameter is type `C extends UiHandlers`.  The interface that RequirementsPanelPresenter is implementing, `RequirementsPanelUiHandler`, extends `UiHandlers`.

Comment: At a glance, I'd expect it to be `public abstract class ApplicationPanelPresenter<V extends ApplicationPanelPresenter.ApplicationPanelView>
        extends PresenterWithBreadCrumb<V> {`.  Your code is too complex for me to tell at a glance if that'll fix it, though.

Comment: `this` is interpreted as `RequirementsPanelPresenter` (read the message carefully) but the compiler doesn't find a method on `ApplicationPanelPresenter.ApplicationPanelView` that fits the signature.

Comment: @LouisWasserman at a glance, you nailed it.  If you want to post an answer I will accept it.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I agree with @LouisWasserman. Assuming the method `getView()` is inside `PresenterWithBreadCrumb` passing `ApplicationPanelPresenter.ApplicationPanelView` as the generic parameter will make the method return exactly that and this interface/class doesn't provide the method in question. Using `V` instead will make it resolve to `MyView`.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I have to wait 5 minutes to accept the answer but I will.  Great and quick feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a glance, I'd expect it to be

```
public abstract class ApplicationPanelPresenter<
        V extends ApplicationPanelPresenter.ApplicationPanelView> 
    extends PresenterWithBreadCrumb<V> {
```

Your code is too complex for me to tell at a glance if that'll fix it, though.